# How to switch xml layout from spinner selection

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm developing a simple BMI calculator for android. I have input fields for lbs, feet, and inches. I want to give users the ability to switch from imperial units to metric, so I added a spinner widget with imperial and metric as options. If the user changes the spinner to metric, I want to be able to change the XML layout so that the input fields are kg and cm. What is the best way to change the XML layout when the user switches between metric and imperial?

I tried creating a new activity that loads the metric layout XML when the user switches to it, but it seems like a poor design to create a new activity just to switch units. I also tried simply using setContentLayout to set the layout to metric.xml if spinner has metric selected and imperial.xml if imperial is selected. This sort of works but the ads and spinner widgets are no longer configured after switching between the layouts. I am still new to android development so I am wondering what the best approach to this would be? I am simply trying to make a slight layout change when the user switches between the different unit options. Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would put everything inside activity layout xml file and toggle based on the condition like this

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/feet"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/inch"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:visibility="gone"/>
```

And in your spinner adapter selection listener, you can toggle the view you want to show:

```
feet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: Wow, great idea. Does that mean the kg and lbs fields would be stacked on top of each other, but only one would be visible/active at a time?

Comment: Yes, and you can use `FrameLayout` or the newest one `ConstraintLayout` as a wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout. It allow you to make to different layouts on each other (different views can be located on another views). For example:

```
<FrameLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/digital_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="294dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp">



        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner101"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox100"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView100"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView102"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner101"
            android:text="Value pulse"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="visible"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView107"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView106"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView103"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="11%"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/analog_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Constant"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:onClick="onResetClick"
        android:text="Reset" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/delitel1"
        android:layout_width="234dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#004f9b" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/delitel1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Language:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, you need to give different id to each RelativeLayouts. Here there are `android:id="@+id/digital_layout"` and `android:id="@+id/analog_layout"`.

And in code need to write handler for your spinner:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                digital_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                analog_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
            case 1:
                digital_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                analog_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
            etc.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, I haven't heard of FrameLayouts before but they seem like they could be useful. Instead of toggling visibility of individual xml components, you are toggling entire layouts stacked on top of each other?

Comment: Yes, sometimes its usefull. You can toggling different layouts, so you don't need to write long code for each component of xml file